# how should I interpret the output of glewinfo?

Tags: opengl, glew

running glewinfo has a lot of information, but some of it is more confusing than helpful.

Here is my glewinfo from a laptop I have http://pastebin.com/K5p37w8a

It tells me my OpenGL version is `2.1`, but when I continue reading, there are entries to `GL_VERSION_3_0` up to `GL_VERSION_4_0`, and all of them say `OK`. But I can't call any of the functions listed there.

Others are tagging with `OK [MISSING]` this is the most confusing of them all, because either it is there, or it is missing, but it can't be both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glewinfo` program shows you all of the entry points (functions) which are present, it doesn't tell you whether you can use the features, or whether those entry points work.  A function could report as OK but your program could still crash if you call it!  To figure out what features are available, you will have to look at the extension strings and the version number.  You can get this information from `glxinfo`, you do not need GLEW.

In this case, you are using Mesa (an OpenGL implementation) with a compatibility profile (which is the default profile).  In compatibility mode, Mesa is limited to OpenGL 2.1.  However, if you request a core profile, Mesa will provide newer features and support a newer version of OpenGL.  The same Mesa library is still used, which is why all of the OpenGL 4.0 entry points are available.

However, GLEW is somewhat broken when you use it with the core profile.  The `glewExperimental` "fix" is a poor band-aid on a flawed implementation.  For this reason, I do not recommend GLEW.  [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) is a good alternative.

Comment: I just wrote a little test program, and I can not create an opengl 3 context at all. glxinfo also has this information: `Max core profile version: 0.0` and `Max compat profile version: 2.1`. So I still don't know what this `GL_VERSION_3_0` entry is supposed to mean, when I can't call any function from it.

Comment: As I explained, `GL_VERSION_3_0` only tells you whether the functions *exist* it does not tell you if the functions *work*.  You can basically ignore `glewinfo` because it doesn't tell you what you want to know, use `glxinfo` instead.  I believe your hardware is OpenGL 2.x class hardware anyway.